# Minimal Non-Symmetric Closed Tracks Under 45-Degree Rotations

Tags: graph-theory, symmetry

Given an arbitrary number of clockwise and anti-clockwise 45-degree track turns, what is the smallest closed track, that is neither axisymmetric nor rotationally symmetrical? For example, AAAAAAAA would be a simple cycle, where A represents a clockwise turn.

There exists a track of length 40 that satisfies all conditions:
AAAABBSBBAAAASAAAABBBBAASAAS
where S=ABBA.

The problem can be formalized as a finite sequence $(v_1,\ldots , v_n)$ with $v_k\in \{\frac{\pi}{4},-\frac{\pi}{4}\}$ and two recursively defined sequence
\begin{align}
r_1&:= 0\\
r_{k+1}&:= r_k + v_k\\
p_1 &:= \left(\begin{array}
10\\
0\end{array}\right)\\
p_{k+1}&:= p_k + \left(\begin{array}
1\cos (r_{k+1})\\
-\sin (r_{k+1})\end{array}\right)
\end{align}
What is the shortest non-empty sequence, such that $r_{n+1}=0$ and $p_{n+1} = 0$ and the track asymmetric is?

Comment: Hi, I removed your tag mirror.symmetry because mathematically it refers to something entirely different: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mirror_symmetry_(string_theory)